# Such that... used in a single clause

Tags: grammar

***Such*** is placed before a modifier and noun to intensify the quality of the modifier.

***That*** is placed as a conjunction.

> It was such a beautiful film that we watched it fully.

Question is, can we use '***that***' as a **relative** **pronoun** with '***such***' being used before a modifier and noun?

> It was such a beautiful film that mesmerized all of us.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

> It was such a beautiful film that mesmerized all of us.

It makes sense, in an odd way. You're saying that a film mesmerized you all and that the film was beautiful.

Other examples might be:

- It was such a beautiful gift that you gave me.
- It was such nice weather that we had yesterday.
- Those were such wonderful examples that you gave me, Astralbee.

They all sound quite formal, and you are more likely to hear other renderings of these.